# Indexing a vector using colon symbol and minus sign in R

Tags: r

```
vector = 1:10
vector[10:1]
vector[10:2-1]
```

- vector[10:1] returns 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
- vector[10:2-1] returns 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

Why does vector[10:2-1] return from 9 instead of 10?

I am scratching my head over this in R. Thank you.

Comment: See the output of `10:2-1`.

Answer (score 0):

it's subtracting the 1 from the whole vector 10:2, so the index becomes 9:1

Comment: To put this answer another way, what's happening is `(10:2) - 1`. To get what you're expecting would be `10:(2-1)` or better yet use `seq(10, 2-1)`